# Finding the limit using L׳Hospital rule

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate the limit:
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty }\left(\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 12} - x\right)
> $$

I know the limit is 2 but I am having hard time showing it.

Comment: This same questiion, posted by the same user, and now deleted, (it was closed as an abstract duplicate yesterday.)

Comment: I think a Laurent series for $\sqrt{x}$ "at" $+\infty$ might suffice here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+4x+12}-x\times\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+12}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+12}+x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{4x(1+\frac {3}{x})}{x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 4x+\frac{12}{x^2}}+1\right)}=2$$

Answer (score 3):

Write

$$ \sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 12} - x = (\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 12} - x) \cdot \frac{  \sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 12 } + x }{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 12} + x } = \frac{4x+12}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 12} + x}  $$

Answer (score 2):

With $x=1/t$, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+4x+12}-x\bigr)=
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+4t+12t^2}-1}{t}
$$
No l'Hôpital needed, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Put $x+2=\sqrt{8}\sinh(t).$

when $x\to+\infty,\; t\to+\infty$.
we have
$$x^2+4x+12=(x+2)^2+8$$

and

$\cosh^2(t)-\sinh^2(t)=1$.
$\implies$
$$\sqrt{x^2+4x+12}-x=\sqrt{8}(\cosh(t)-\sinh(t))+2$$

$$=\sqrt{8}e^{-t}+2.$$

the limit when $t\to+\infty\;$ is $\;2$.

Comment: Was thinking of $$x+2=2\sqrt2\tan t$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with the Squeeze Theorem.

Noting that $x^2+4x+12=(x+2)^2+8$, we have

$$(x+2)^2\lt (x+2)^2+8\lt(x+2)^2+8+{16\over(x+2)^2}=\left(x+2+{4\over x+2}\right)^2$$

and therefore, since everything being squared is positive for $x\to\infty$,

$$x+2\lt\sqrt{x^2+4x+12}\lt x+2+{4\over x+2}$$

or

$$2\lt\sqrt{x^2+4x+12}-x\lt 2+{4\over x+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is this nice formula:                                                   $$\lim_{x\to{\infty}} (ax^n+bx^{n-1}+...)^{1\over n} -a^{1\over n} |x+{b\over na}| =0$$  using this fact we can say: $$\lim_{x\to {\infty} }(x^2+4x+12)^{{1\over 2}} -x= x+({4\over 2}) -x =2$$

Comment: These equations don't really make sense:  you have $x$ tending to a limit on the left, but just sitting there on the right.

Comment: You are right . The limit should be in both sides . O

Comment: I will edit  it accordingly

Comment: It should be fixed now.

Comment: The problem now is that the first formula technically just says $\infty=\infty$.

Comment: The limiting value exists iff the  function is a polynomial of the same degree is being rooted,pay close attention to that.

Comment: @Barrycipra and $\infty=\infty$ is completely valid. Becuase  the only fact that has been used is that the behaviour of the LHS  becomes close to the behaviour of the RHS .

Comment: As assertion of the form $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x)$ is not equivalent to $\lim(f(x)-g(x))=0$ when $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x)=\infty$.  You mean the latter, with $f(x)=(ax^n+bx^{n-1}+\cdots)^{1/n}$ and $g(x)=a^{1/n}|x+(b/na)|$.